# Can I customise my data text field in an MVC SelectList for use with the HtmlHelper.DropDownList without having to create a new struct or class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am creating a SelectList from a List(T) class to use to populate a HtmlHelper.DropDownList in an MVC view, setting the dataValueField and dataTextField in the Select List constructor.  The text that should be displayed doesn't excatly match one of the properties on my class and still needs to be manipulated.  Is there any way of doing this through the SelectList constructor?  I realise I could do this by creating a struct or class to use as the IEnumerable input for the Select list but I'd prefer not if I don't need to.

My Controller code is currently:

```
        var members = MemberService.GetAll();
        this.ViewData["Members"] = new SelectList(members, "Id", "Name");
```

My View code is currently:

```
        <%= Html.DropDownList("Members") %>
```

Instead of "Surname" as my display field I'd like to be able to preformat the field by combining (and formatting) two properties.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can create loop through the members list, adding the values to a new list that you then create the SelectList from.  Something like:

```
var members = MemberService.GetAll();
List<object> newList = new List<object>();
foreach(var member in members)
    newList.Add( new { 
        Id = member.Id, 
        Name = member.Name + " " + member.Surname 
    } );
this.ViewData["Members"] = new SelectList(newList, "Id", "Name");
```

I can't remember if you can use an anonymous type like that or not, but if not you can create an small data class to use as an intermediary.

Comment: That works perfectly and was exactly what I was trying to do.  Thank you.

Comment: Instead of adding anonymous type you can add partial class for your model and add a property:
public string CustomName { get { return Name + " " + Surname } }
This is make it useful in several places though the project.

Answer (score 15):

You can create an extension method and set whatever you want as the text. It could be something as

```
public static IList<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> itemsToMap, Func<T, string> textProperty, Func<T, string> valueProperty, Predicate<T> isSelected)
{
    var result = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var item in itemsToMap)
    {
        result.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = valueProperty(item),
            Text = textProperty(item),
            Selected = isSelected(item)
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you call this method as:

```
var membersSelectList = MemberService.GetAll().ToSelectList(m=>m.FirstName + " " + m.Surname, m.Id.ToString(), m=>m.Id < -1); //Any predicate you need here.
```

Answer (score 5):

For those that use LINQ. 
Instead of:

```
    var members = MemberService.GetAll();
```

you can use:

```
    ViewBag.MembersList = new SelectList(
    from x in db.members where x.role = 5 select new {x.ID, x.Name, x.Surname, S_Name = x.Surname + " " + x.Name}, 
    "ID", "S_Name");
```

and then use ViewBag.MemberList in your Razor code like

```
    @Html.DropDownList("MembersList", String.Empty)
```