# mvc fill dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, drop-down-menu

i use this code to fill dropdownlist

```
ViewData["projectType"] = new SelectList  
  (_dataManager.Project.ProjectTypeList(), "Id", "Name");
```

but what i must do if i want to use not one table column but two or more columns? for example

```
ViewData["projectType"] = new SelectList  
  (_dataManager.Project.ProjectTypeList(), "Id", "Name1"+"Name2");
```

Comment: There is a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319691/can-i-customise-my-data-text-field-in-an-mvc-selectlist-for-use-with-the-htmlhelp/2319842#2319842

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a property to your <strike>model</strike> ViewModel:

```
public partial class Project
{
    public string FullName 
    {
        get { return Name1 + Name2; }
    }
}
```

and use this property:

```
ViewData["projectType"] = new SelectList(
    _dataManager.Project.ProjectTypeList(), 
    "Id", 
    "FullName"
);
```

Comment: If `FullName` is necessary for presentation only, this should be avoided.

Comment: That's why a ViewModel should be used. Model -> ViewModel -> View. The ViewModel is what you present to the View so such property is allowed there.

Answer (score 0):

You can always fill `SelectList` manually.

Something like (i didn't test it):

```
var list = new SelectList();
var data = _dataManager.Project.ProjectTypeList();

foreach (var d in data){
  list.Add(new SelectListItem  
    (string.Format("{0} {1}",d.Name1,d.Name2), d.Id, isChecked));
}
ViewData["projectType"] = list;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something similar to this:

```
ViewData["service_lines"] = new SelectList  
     (repository.SubcontractService_Lines(), "Id", "Name");
```

In Repository:

```
    public class SelectService_LineItem  
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public Guid Id { get; set; }
            }

    public IEnumerable<SelectService_LineItem> SubcontractService_Lines() 
    {
        return
            from sl in db.service_lines
            select new SelectService_LineItem
            {
                Name = sl.service_line_name + "" + sl.service_line_name2,
                Id = sl.service_line_id
            };
    }
```