# Display two properties in the dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Database table

Language

- languageID (Primary key)
- language
- People

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("SprakID", new SelectList(ViewData["Sprak"] as IEnumerable, "languageID", "language", Model.languageID))%>
```

Goal:
Display the name of the language and what languageID in the DropDownList.

Problem:
Don't know how to display both language and languageID in the dropdownlist?

Comment: Didn't understand your question, do you mean something similar that it was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319691/can-i-customise-my-data-text-field-in-an-mvc-selectlist-for-use-with-the-htmlhelp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a property to your Language class, for example

```
 public string DataTextFieldLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} ({1})", language, languageId);
        }
    }
```

Now use it for the dataTextField

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("SprakID", new SelectList(ViewData["Sprak"] as IEnumerable, "languageID", "DataTextFieldLabel", Model.languageID))%>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you should use the [NotMapped] Data Annotation to exclude this property from your EF Code-First Analysis (so that it will exist within your POCO but not become a column in your DB Table)

Answer (score 2):

DropDownLists only have DataValueField and DataTextField properties, so one thing I can think of is to make a read-only property that combines both the name of the language and the ID, formatted the way you want it, and have the DropDownList use that for the DataTextField.