# MVC DropDownListFor getting 2 names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, variables, html.dropdownlistfor

Hi I am developing a banking system for a school assignment. Can you pass 2 Names in a dropdownlist ex:

This is the model

```
public TransferModel(int bankId, int userid)
{
    myAccount = new Service1Client().getAccountByID(bankId);
    AccountList = new SelectList(new Service1Client().RetrieveAllAccountsByAccountId(userid), "Id", "Name");
}
```

I am setting Id, Name to the Select List

View:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    Withdraw From: <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model =>  model.myAccount.Id, Model.AccountList)%>
</div>
```

the Select list will only display the name of the accounts. is their by any chance to display the name and the balance in the drop down list.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate. Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868627/display-two-properties-in-the-dropdownlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following would be quite a tidy way of handling this:

```
public class AccountModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Decimal Balance { get; set; }

    public string AccountSummary
    {
       get
       {
           return String.Format("{0} ({1:C})", Name, Balance);
       }
    }
}

public class TransferModel
{
    public IList<AccountModel> Accounts { get; set; }
    public string SelectedAccountId { get; set; }
    /* Whatever other properties your view needs */
}
```

Type your view to `TransferModel` and do:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model =>  model.SelectedAccountId,
    new SelectList { Model.Accounts, "Id", "AccountSummary" )%>
```