# Custom value in MVC ListBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, listbox

I have a list of items I want to show in a ListBox in a page of a MVC web application (MVC 4 to be precise). Following the lead of [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136730/ASP-NET-MVC-2-Basics-Working-with-ListBoxes?fid=1601043&df=90&mpp=10&noise=1&prof=True&sort=Position&view=Quick&spc=Relaxed), I easily made the ListBox.

However, now I need to use a custom value as my "value" member (sorry for the pun). Let's say that instead of

```
Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.AvailableSelected, 
    new MultiSelectList(Model.AvailableProducts, "Id", 
    "Name", Model.AvailableSelected), 
    new { size = "6" })
```

I need (code made up, not working)

```
Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.AvailableSelected, 
    new MultiSelectList(Model.AvailableProducts, "Id + CategoryId", 
    "Name", Model.AvailableSelected), 
    new { size = "6" })
```

In other words I need to build the value based on other fields or variables. I know a solution would be to actually add this "fake" field in the item class, but I find this quite ugly and I think it's bad practice (implementing a field only for a specific quasi-presentation need).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The answer was here on SO, but I couldn't find it before posting. Sorry about that.

See this thread: [Can I customise my data text field in an MVC SelectList for use with the HtmlHelper.DropDownList without having to create a new struct or class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319691/can-i-customise-my-data-text-field-in-an-mvc-selectlist-for-use-with-the-htmlhel)

I suggest using @uvita's answer, even though it's not currently marked as the accepted answer.