# SelectList formatting for dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Cars Brand/Models class which contains
ID
Car_brand (example: BMW,Audi)
Car_model (Example: M5, A4)

How can I format selectlist to pass Car_brand+Car_model to dropdownlist?

```
  @Html.DropDownList("smodelis", new SelectList(ViewBag.Smodel, "model_name", "model_id"), "Modelis", new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"})
```

Comment: Please show what you have done

Comment: I have used only model_name. Now I need both: model name and brand name

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319691/can-i-customise-my-data-text-field-in-an-mvc-selectlist-for-use-with-the-htmlhel