# Modify DropdownList items in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

I am really confused how DropdownList works in MVC

I basically have table Employee that has EmployeeID and  EmployeeReportsToID. So whenever I edit/Create an Employee I want to have DropdownList for field EmployeeReportsToID where items are from Employee table itself.

Below is code that I have and it works good.

controller

```
ViewBag.EmployeeReportsToID = new SelectList(db.Employees.ToList(), "Employeeid", "Description", Employee.EmployeeReportsToID);
```

view

```
<div class="col-md-10">@Html.DropDownList("EmployeeReportsToID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })  </div>
```

Now I have few questions

1. How does dropdownList knows where to bring items from. My parameter in  DropDownList is null.
2. How can I modify items that are in DropdownList. I basically want to add Employee title to their name manually based on some field in same table. For example items can be as below.

> Employee 1 - Sales Manager
>
> Employee 2 - VP
>
> Employee 3 - Developer
>
> Employee 4 - Developer
>
> Employee 5 - Software Manager

Comment: The code does not work - you have an extra `)` after `.ToList()` - but assume that's just a typo :). Show you model for `Employees` (which extra property do you want to add?)

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Yes it's typo. Extra property can be any string field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.EmployeeReports = new SelectList(db.Employees.ToList()), "Employeeid", "Description");
```

For populating your dropdownlist you can use [this extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2319842/1646540) and set whatever you want as the text:

```
public static IList<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> itemsToMap, Func<T, string> textProperty, Func<T, string> valueProperty, Predicate<T> isSelected)
{
    var result = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var item in itemsToMap)
    {
        result.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = valueProperty(item),
            Text = textProperty(item),
            Selected = isSelected(item)
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you call this method as:

```
ViewBag.EmployeeReports = db.Employees.ToList().ToSelectList(m => m.EmployeeId + " - " + m.EmployeeName, m.Id.ToString(), m => m.Id < -1);
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("EmployeeReportsToID", (SelectList)ViewBag.EmployeeReports, "-- Select ---", new { id= "reqType", @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thanks Sirwan. It helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the below code, `EmployeeReportsToID` tells where to get list from.

   `@Html.DropDownList("EmployeeReportsToID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })`

   `EmployeeReportsToID` works as source of data. You can actually use other html helper which is `DropdownListFor` if you are using strongly typed view.It looks as follow

   `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmployeeReportsToID, Model.EmployeeReports, "Select one")`
2. try this code

   `ViewBag.EmployeeReportsToID = = Employee.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
               {
                   Text = x.EmployeeReportToId+" - "+x.EmployeeTitle,
                   Value = x.EmployeeReportToId
               });
               return list.ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

Part 1.

When you provide `null` to the second parameter of `DropDownList()`, the method falls back to searching the `ViewDataDictionary` for a property matching the first parameter, and if that property (in your case `EmployeeReportsToID`) is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (which it is) it will use it.

Part 2.

You can generate a collection of `SelectListItems` and set the `Text` property

```
ViewBag.EmployeeReportsToID = new db.Employees.Select(e => new SelectListItem
{
  Value = e.Employeeid.ToString(), // assumes its typeof int
  Text = e.Description + " - " + e.SomeOtherProperty
});
```

However, its recommended you use the strongly typed helper to bind to a property in your model. For example if the model in the view has a property (say) `int EmployeeReportsToID`, then

```
ViewBag.EmployeeList = new SelectList(db.Employees, "Employeeid", "Description"); // do not need .ToList()
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmployeeReportsToID, (SelectList)ViewBag.EmployeeList, "Please select")
```